# Where to keep JSON files in a Rails project to repopulate the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Nokogiri to scraping and populate the database, but the process is slow (2~3 hours), I'd like to keep these data in JSON files to easily repopulate my database during development. 
It is a good practice? What is the best place to keep these files in a Rails project?

Comment: A more straightforward solution might to simply export your database and import into a development database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about seed data. If you put ruby code to load this seed data in `db/seeds.rb`, you can then run `rake db:seed` to run it [as mentioned in the Active Record Migrations Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data).

I would probably end up making a `db/seeds` or`db/seed_data` directory, putting the JSON files in there, and then writing ruby in `db/seeds.rb` that would iterate through those JSON files and load all the data in them.